# Pandas Dataframe converting to pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe like below. I want to convert it to pivot table format, where there is each row for unique ID, new column for each Score with Type prefix.

I have about 15 different Types in the actual dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                   'Type':['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
                   'Score':[0.3,np.nan, 0.2, 0.1, 1.1,np.nan, 2, np.nan]})
```

Desired output

| ID | A_Score | B_Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 |  |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 1.1 |  |
| 4 | 2 |  |

I tried below and it almost does what I need but I need the column renames and need it in pandas dataframe

`df2  = df.pivot_table(index=['ID'], columns='Type')`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
out = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Type',values='Score').add_prefix('Score_').reset_index()
Out[355]: 
Type  ID  Score_A  Score_B
0      1      0.3      NaN
1      2      0.2      0.1
2      3      1.1      NaN
3      4      2.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```py
df = df.set_index(["ID", "Type"]).unstack(1)
df.columns = [f"{b}_{a}" for a, b in df.columns]
print(df.reset_index().fillna(""))
```

Prints:

```
   ID  A_Score B_Score
0   1      0.3        
1   2      0.2     0.1
2   3      1.1        
3   4      2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your multiIndex header using map-join

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    Score_A  Score_B
ID                  
1       0.3      NaN
2       0.2      0.1
3       1.1      NaN
4       2.0      NaN
```